# 'accessibilityobject' threw an exception of type 'system.invalidoperationexception'

Tags: c#, winforms

There are a lot of questions on SO about `'system.invalidoperationexception`' but none of them have helped me figure this out.

I have a `datatable` (`tab2tableExtra`) that gets its values from another `datatable` (`tab2table`), which in turn gets is values from a database. `tab2tableExtra` only contains 4 rows and 8 columns and all its values (barring column [0]) are calculated from `tab2table`. Specifically two columns in `tab2table` are used to drive a for loop and those seem to be at the crux of the problem. These are `MLevel` and `RLevel`, which are shown in the code below.

Everything works perfectly when both the `MLevel` column and `RLevel` column have some non-null values. But if one of those columns is all nulls (`DBNull.Value` -which can happen on occasion), then something seems to go wrong. Interestingly, it doesn't actually cause the code to break, but it seems to mess with the calculated values in `tab2tableExtra`, as the entire table is null (except for column [0], which is just 1, 2, 3, 4).

Upon debugging, when either `MLevel` or `RLevel` (but not both) contains all null I see a 'system.invalidoperationexception`from`this`, as shown in the figure below. What causes the code to do is break out of the for loop after one iteration, and then not perform any of the rest of calculations.
[image: Error messages]

This message comes from the following code:

```
// Add values to tab2tableExtra
                // Add Levels columns
                DataRow row = tab2tableExtra.NewRow();
                for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    row = tab2tableExtra.NewRow();
                    row["Level"] = i;
                    tab2tableExtra.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                // Add participation rate column values
                DataRow dr = tab2tableExtra.Rows[0];
                int rowCount = tab2table.Rows.Count;

                /*int countnumM = tab2table.AsEnumerable().Where(x => int.Parse(x["MLevel"].ToString()) == 1 || 
                                int.Parse(x["MLevel"].ToString()) == 2 || int.Parse(x["MLevel"].ToString()) == 3 || 
                                int.Parse(x["MLevel"].ToString()) == 4).ToList().Count;*/
                int countnumM = tab2table.AsEnumerable().Select(x => int.TryParse(x["MLevel"].ToString(), out var d) ? d : (int?)null).Where(x => x >= 1 && x <= 4).Count();
                int countnumRW = tab2table.AsEnumerable().Select(x => int.TryParse(x["RLevel"].ToString(), out var d) ? d : (int?)null).Where(x => x >= 1 && x <= 4).Count();

                /*int countnumRW = tab2table.AsEnumerable().Where(x => int.Parse(x["RLevel"].ToString()) == 1 || int.Parse(x["RLevel"].ToString()) == 2 ||
                                                    int.Parse(x["RLevel"].ToString()) == 3 || int.Parse(x["RLevel"].ToString()) == 4).ToList().Count;*/

                for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    if (countnumM > 0)
                    {
                        float levelPercM = Convert.ToInt32(tab2table.Compute("COUNT(MLevel)", "MLevel =" + i.ToString()));
                        tab2tableExtra.Rows[i - 1][1] = Math.Round(100 * levelPercM / countnumM, 2);
                    }
                    else
                        tab2tableExtra.Rows[i - 1][1] = null;
                    if (countnumRW > 0)
                    {
                        decimal levelPercRW = Convert.ToDecimal(tab2table.Compute("COUNT([RLevel])", "RLevel =" + i.ToString()));
                        tab2tableExtra.Rows[i - 1][2] = Math.Round(100 * levelPercRW / countnumRW, 2);
                    }
                    else
                        tab2tableExtra.Rows[i - 1][2] = null;
                }
                // Add the rest of the column values that only require a single number
                tab2tableExtra.Rows[0][3] = rowCount;
                if (countnumM > 0)
                    tab2tableExtra.Rows[0][4] = 100*countnumM/rowCount;
                else
                    tab2tableExtra.Rows[0][4] = null;
                if (countnumRW > 0)
                    tab2tableExtra.Rows[0][5] = 100*countnumRW/rowCount;
                else
                    tab2tableExtra.Rows[0][5] = null;
                decimal RWavg = Convert.ToDecimal(tab2table.Compute("AVG([ROverall])", ""));
                decimal Mavg = Convert.ToDecimal(tab2table.Compute("AVG([MOverall])", ""));

                tab2tableExtra.Rows[0][6] = RWavg;
                tab2tableExtra.Rows[0][7] = Mavg;
```

For reference, when I debug with a `tab2table` that has at least one non-null value in both `MLevel` and `RLevel`, I see this:
[image: No Errors]

If anyone knows how to solve this, or even just why this happening, it would be very useful.

Comment: It's likely that the exception you're seeing has nothing to do with anything. When you expand `this` in the Autos window it's going to try to show you all of the properties of `this` (the form.) The exception is probably happening when it tries to read that property. So it's not an exception from your code - it's actually from this window, just like all the other exceptions you see. Even if you see the error sometimes but not others it could be because of the state of the form at that moment. Unless some exception in your code is mentioning that object I'd disregard it.

Comment: @ScottHannen So how do I fix the problem if I don't know what it is?

Comment: The third paragraph describes what I think is the real problem - you're seeing some unexpected values under certain conditions. I recommend formulating the question more around that code. What's happening is that people (including me) are skipping past that to the pictures and then realizing that's not where the problem is. I'll look at the code itself some more and see if something jumps out.

Comment: @ScottHannen thank you! If you don't see anything I will try to formulate a question around the code itself. Though, my problem there is that I am sure what to ask. This is such an odd problem and I have never encountered anything like it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Scott Hannen said, the problem here has nothing to do with the `'system.invalidoperationexception'` exception. For anyone who comes across a similar problem, the actually issue was with the `null`.

It turns out, in C# datatables cannot handle `null` values. And instead of giving an error, it simply just stops filling the datatable once it encounters one. In order to fix this, one has to make sure to use `DBNull.Value`. So in the code in question, for example, changing all `null` to `DBNull.Value` will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In these lines of code:

```
int countnumM = tab2table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => int.TryParse(x["MLevel"].ToString(), out var d) ? d : (int?)null)
    .Where(x => x >= 1 && x <= 4).Count();
int countnumRW = tab2table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => int.TryParse(x["RLevel"].ToString(), out var d) ? d : (int?)null)
    .Where(x => x >= 1 && x <= 4).Count();
```

You're using `int.TryParse` to read the value of `x["MLevel"]`.

If `x["MLevel"].ToString()` doesn't return a `string` that can be parsed as an `int` then `int.TryParse` will return false. That includes if `x` is `DBNull.Value`. That won't get parsed as an `int`.

Then, after the `TryParse`, you have this: `? d : (int?)null)`

In other words, if `TryParse` returned true - it was able to parse, then you're selecting `d` - the parsed value.

But if it couldn't parse the value - `TryParse` returned false - then you're returning `(int?)null` - which is effectively null.

At the end you're filtering the results for values between 1 and 4, and then counting the number of those results:

```
.Where(x => x >= 1 && x <= 4).Count();
```

Just as you described, if there were *some* non-null values then that `Count` will probably return one or more. But if there are *all* null values then `.Count`  will equal 0, because no values were between 1 and 4.

In that case `countnumM` and/or `countnumRW` would equal 0.

Further down you're setting some additional values `if countnumM > 0` and `if countnumRW > 0`. But they're not greater than 0. They are 0. If they are 0, you're code will do what you expect:

```
           for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (countnumM > 0) // this is == 0
                {
                    float levelPercM = Convert.ToInt32(tab2table.Compute("COUNT(MLevel)", "MLevel =" + i.ToString()));
                    tab2tableExtra.Rows[i - 1][1] = Math.Round(100 * levelPercM / countnumM, 2);
                }
                else               // This is what's happening
                    tab2tableExtra.Rows[i - 1][1] = null;

                if (countnumRW > 0) // this is == 0
                {
                    decimal levelPercRW = Convert.ToDecimal(tab2table.Compute("COUNT([RLevel])", "RLevel =" + i.ToString()));
                    tab2tableExtra.Rows[i - 1][2] = Math.Round(100 * levelPercRW / countnumRW, 2);
                }
                else                // This is what's happening
                    tab2tableExtra.Rows[i - 1][2] = null;
            }
```

---

To clarify around the other part - the `InvalidOperationException`:

When you're in the debugger and you inspect the properties of a variable, it's going to try to display the value of each property. That's what the list of properties is in your image - it's all the properties of `this`.

Some of them might be properties you don't use or care about, but when it tries to read the properties so it can show them to you, the property throws an exception. So now instead of a property value it shows you the exception it got when trying to read the property.

This is understandably confusing because you're debugging trying to figure out what's going on in your code, and then you see exceptions. You wonder if they might be related to the problem.

Generally they aren't because if *your* code throws an exception then it stops execution of your code. That's an exception you would need to figure out. But if it doesn't stop your code from running and it's a property on some framework class (like `Form.AccessibilityObject`) that you aren't even using, then you can usually ignore it.

Comment: How come the problems when only one of either `RLevel` or `MLevel` are null? That would make sense if both were null, but since `countnumM` or `countnumRW` will always have non-null values, shouldn't it continue through with all the computations involving that one?

Comment: I missed something. A null value *would* throw an exception because calling `.ToString()` on a null would throw a `NullReferenceException`. Are you saying that sometimes `x["MLevel"]` itself contains a null value? Or is it something like `DBNull.Value` (which isn't the same as null?)

Comment: It should be a `DBNUll.Value` because it's data taken directly from a database. When I step through, I get 0 for either of the `countnum` variables if they are all nulls, otherwise I get a nonzero int. It's on the for loop that things seem to break down, and I can't seem to understand why.

Comment: Also, if you look at the code commented out, it does not contain `TryParse`, but still produces the exact same results except that it never enters the for loop. It exits the code at `countnumRW`.

Comment: I updated the answer. Now I think I see what's happening. What helps a lot is if we separate the code into smaller pieces. That makes it easier to read one small part, test it, and see if it does what we think. Unit tests also help. That way when something goes wrong it's much easier to spot the part where it happens.

Comment: The commented part will work if there are no nulls and the values represent integers. If there's a null then it's like calling `int.Parse("DBNull.Value")`. It will throw an exception. My first reaction was that was why it was changed from `Parse` to `TryParse`.

Comment: The thing is, that's exactly what I want to happen. The issue here is that one of either `cuntnumM` or `countnumRW` are ***always*** non-null. That should mean that it should enter the for loop and iterate through one of the if statements. Moreover, it should continue on and do the rest of the calculations. the interesting thing is that when one of them is null, even `RWavg` and `Mavg` are null, which are wholly independent of `countnum`